# Getting email address as endnote in LyX revtex document

Tags: lyx, punctuation, revtex, endnotes

I'm having trouble getting the author email address to appear as an endnote -- marked with a letter -- in a LyX `revtex` document. Instead, it's showing up as a footnote.

Here's a [`.lyx` document](https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/lnmaurer/web/lyxhelp/test.lyx) and an associated [`.bib` file](https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/lnmaurer/web/lyxhelp/test.bib) as an example.

EDIT:

[Here](http://pages.citebite.com/j3f7r8x1sdtb)'s a description of the endnote I'm talking about:

> Auxiliary author information, for instance including email addresses, should be listed at the beginning of the endnote section using superscripted Latin letters followed by right parentheses (e.g.," c) ").

I can now get the email address to go to the right place using the `prb` option, and I can the endnote to be a letter with the `altaffilletter` option, **but I still can't get the right parenthesis**.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following as part of an ERT at the end of your document:

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\def\frontmatter@thefootnote{%
  \altaffilletter@sw{\@alph}{\@fnsymbol}\c@footnote)%
}%
\makeatother
```

This adds the necessary parenthesis at the end of the marker as required:

[image]